# Map with object and list of objects to Json

Tags: java, json, gson

I have got two main model classes: `Customer` and `Product`

```
public class Customer {
    String name;
    String surname;
    int age;
    BigDecimal cash;
}

public class Product {
    String name;
    Category category;
    BigDecimal price;
}
```

I want to build `json` file with `Map<Customer, List<Product>>`
When I write to `json` file data with my method which works correct - I am sure about this - the `json` file shows this syntax

```
{
  "Customer{name\u003d\u0027Custo1\u0027, surname\u003d\u0027Surname\u0027, age\u003d18, cash\u003d1200}": [
    {
      "name": "prod1",
      "category": "CLOTHES",
      "price": 12000
    },
    {
      "name": "prod2",
      "category": "ELECTRONIC",
      "price": 15000
    }
  ]
}
```

Then when i want to read this file, the error `Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present` occurs so I think that the `Customer` syntax from json file is not recognized.
So I tried to write data to `json` file on my own with this syntax below, but it does not work

```
[
  {
    "name": "Abc",
    "surname": "Def",
    "age": 14,
    "cash": "2000"
  }
  :
  [
    {
      "name": "prod1",
      "category": "CLOTHES",
      "price": 12000
    },
    {
      "name": "prod2",
      "category": "ELECTRONIC",
      "price": 15000
    }
  ]
]
```

---

json converter method:

```
  public void toJson(final T item) {
        try (FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(jsonFilename)) {
            fileWriter.write(gson.toJson(item));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ValidatorException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Whatever wrote the first JSON looks broken and the second "JSON" isn't one, that's invalid syntax

Comment: @ETO first i tried to write my own syntax but it did not work so i used my `toJson` method to write this file automatically and see what will be the syntax of it but as you can see, it is  broken, there is my `toJson` method in post

Comment: @Tom could you show me the correct syntax then?

Comment: You need to store your list of products in Customer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@Tom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3824919/tom) is right on the issues you've faced with. I'll explain why and suggest one more solution.

Your first JSON is technically a valid JSON but it cannot be deserialized, because the map keys are results of the `Customer.toString()` method Gson uses by default. This is why it looks weird, acts like a debug string, and can't be deserialized back: there it is almost always no way to restore an object from the `toString()` result (`toString` is designed mostly for debugging/logging purposes providing *basic* information regarding the state of a particular object that does not need to expose its all internals at all).

Your second JSON is [invalid](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) JSON. Period.

Tom's suggestion of making the list of products a part of the customer class is totally fine. Having it implemented like that lets you to serialize everything as a list like this:

```json
[
    {
        "name": "john",
        "products": [
            {"name": "prod1"},
            {"name": "prod2"}
        ]
    }
]
```

Hint: separating domain objects (`Customer` and `Product`) and representation objects for data transfer (`CustomerDto` and `ProductDto`) is usually a fine idea too since it allows to create representation for any concrete representation implementation (one for various JSON implementation libraries, two for other-format-oriented tools, third for persistence, four for UI views, etc), so it might be implemented like converting `Map<Customer, List<Product>>` to `List<CustomerDto>` and back (possibly by using mapper-generators like MapStruct).

If for whatever reason it is not possible to reorganize your domain classes or create Gson-friendly DTO-mappings, or you're fine to keep it as simple as possible and you're fine with having not that trivial JSON structure (as long as you understand implications of the format in this solution: evolution, distribution, etc), then you can enable special Gson mode to support this kind of maps. It generates valid JSONs that can be serialized and deserialized back, but the way it is implemented looks a bit of anti-pattern to me because of losing semantics due to using arrays as the data container.

```java
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
final class Customer {

    final String name;

}
```

```java
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
final class Product {

    final String name;

}
```

```java
public final class MapTest {

    private static final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .enableComplexMapKeySerialization()
            .create();

    private static final TypeToken<Map<Customer, List<Product>>> customerToProducts = new TypeToken<Map<Customer, List<Product>>>() {};

    @Test
    public void test() {
        final Map<Customer, List<Product>> ordersBefore = ImmutableMap.of(
                new Customer("john"), ImmutableList.of(new Product("prod1"), new Product("prod2"))
        );
        final String json = gson.toJson(ordersBefore, customerToProducts.getType());
        Assertions.assertEquals("[[{\"name\":\"john\"},[{\"name\":\"prod1\"},{\"name\":\"prod2\"}]]]", json);
        final Map<Customer, List<Product>> ordersAfter = gson.fromJson(json, customerToProducts.getType());
        Assertions.assertEquals(ordersBefore, ordersAfter);
    }

}
```

Note that it generates JSON like this (index `0` means the key, index `1` means the value):

```json
[
    [
        {"name": "john"},
        [
            {"name": "prod1"},
            {"name": "prod2"}
        ]
    ]
]
```